# Flutter Argument passing - Getting a null from routeArgs

Tags: flutter, dart, parameter-passing

I have the following setup of my flutter app:

**HomeScreen.Dart**

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    appBar: homeAppBar(context),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavBar(),
     body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          CategoryList(),
          ItemList(),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

The CategoryList class contains a list view of category items. When a category item is clicked, the associated products should be displayed for that item. The way I do that is by passing the category name to the product item list class. Please see below:

**CategoryItem.dart**

```
class CategoryItemN extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  const CategoryItemNew({
    @required this.title,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => selectCategory(context),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 15),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              title,
              style: isActive
                  ? TextStyle(
                      color: kTextColor,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    )
                  : TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
            ),
            if (isActive)
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                height: 3,
                width: 22,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: kPrimaryColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  void selectCategory(BuildContext ctx) {
    Navigator.of(ctx).pushNamed(
       ItemList.routeName,
      arguments: {
        'title': title  ==== > This is the category name 
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**ItemList.dart**

```
class _ItemListState extends State<ItemList> {
  var _isInit = true;
  var _isLoading = false;
  var title = '';

   void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (_isInit) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });
      
       final routeArgs =
      ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map<String, String>;
      title = routeArgs['title'];  ===================> This is where the error occurs! 
       Provider.of<Products>(context).fetchProducts(title, true).then((_) {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
      });
    }
    _isInit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

Here's the error message:

> ```
> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Listener: The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling []("title")
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can get arguments through 'ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments' in the build().

```
final routeArgs =
      ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map<String, String>;
```

There is a official example about 'Pass arguments to a named route'.

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments

Comment: This won't help me because I am trying to get the title in ItemList.dart so that I can fetch the products before building the widget.